# Jmeter - Is it possible to skip remaining samplers when one sampler fails

Tags: jmeter

I'm automating a test scenario. I have configured few HTTP samplers within a simple controller. I want to skip executing the remaining samplers when one sampler fail.

Ex:

```
Simple Controller

 - http sampler 1
 - http sampler 2
 - http sampler 3
 - http sampler 4
```

If 'sampler 2' fails, I want to skip executing 'sampler 3' and 'sampler 4'.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve.

One option: stop the whole test (or whatever) by providing corresponding configuration on Thread Group level

[image: Thread Group Action Sampler Error]

Another option: conditionally run samplers basing on preceding sampler success:

1. Add [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) after `http sampler 2`
2. Use `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` as "Condition"
3. Add `http sampler 3` and `http sampler 4` as children of the If Controller

[image: If Controller]

See [How to Use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and Get Pie](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) article for more information on setting various conditions in the If Controller